# Sub-domain routing in Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, subdomain, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm using Laravel framework version 5.1 for my web application that will be run on a shared hosting. Since I have a very limited access to this host, (e.g. I don't have a SSH access, can't create virtual hosts inside the machine etc.) I had to make some tricks to run it smoothly. Here is what I've done so far:

1. Moved the files inside of the `public/` directory to my root directory.
2. Changed the file paths of auto load registrar in the `public/index.php` with the new directory.

Everything works as intended except the sub-domain routing. I defined api.myapp.com as wildcard on `routes.php` but when I try to visit this subdomain, Chrome gives me **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** error. Here is the code from `routes.php`:

```
Route::group([
    'domain'     => 'api.myapp.com',
    'prefix'     => 'v1',
    'middleware' => 'cors'
], function () {
    // some RESTful resource controllers
});
```

How can I manage to work this subdomain? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you remember to create that subdomain in your hosting account? The error is pointing to a DNS issue, not a Laravel routing issue.

Comment: @DoyleLewis I don't think that I have to create a subdomain from cPanel for this routing. That is why it's called "wildcard". If I'd use a dynamic subdomain like usernames, then I'd create a subdomain for all users?

Comment: The internet needs to know how to route to your server, then the server needs to know how to route the request to your script. The only way to do that is to have a subdomain setup in cPanel. You can certainly set that up as a wildcard subdomain, then you don't need to set one up for each subdomain you want to use. Lots of layers of routing to work through.

Comment: Setup `*.myapp.com` in cPanel to point to Laravel's `public` folder.

Comment: @Jamesking56 just tried and pointed to /public_html only since I moved the contents of public folder to the root (public_html) but nothing's changed.

Comment: is `*.myapp.com`'s DNS pointed to your server?

Comment: Just made the necessary DNS redirections and everything works well. Thanks guys.